glTF/GLB exporting with multiple actions through NLA not supported?
I need some help with exporting GLTF/GLB with two or more animation tracks that are meant to be toggled on and off in Webflow later.
Exporting the whole thing as a keyframe based animation works, but then I get only one action take. If I then "push down to action" in the NLA editor and split it into two actions, with separate names, upon export, my model rotates 90 degrees and I still only get one track. This rotation doesn't happen with an export to GLTF/GLB from the animation still being just keyframes.
I'm guessing this has to do with how the model is rigged - it's a pre-made animation chosen by my friend for a specific project. Any guesses?
To just see if I got the same result with a super simple scene, I made a 4x keyframe animation of a cube moving around with the same approach I mentioned above, just turning it to an action, splitting the track - and there is no animation data saved in the GLB for this cube.
How do I go about making these two separate takes in a single GLB ? Exporting it with the keyframes being just keyframes worked, though, not through NLA.
(Also, I'm not quite nailing the textures just yet and the glTF is more shiny than the GLB, so I have to figure that out too).
Thank you, and any help is much appreciated
(I'm a beginner Blender user, but have been using C4D for 3-4 years, some work in Maya, some UE4/5 so I'm not a complete beginner, just unfamiliar with this software)
(Windows user)

Is it related to this post: Multiple object animations not exporting to GLB ?

Also read .fbx export why there are no materials or textures for your texturing problem.

As mentionned above, these issues seem to already have answers on this site. I also recommend checking glTF 2.0 - Blender 4.2 Manual. If the provided links do not help, please [edit] your question to provide updated information, as well as provide more details on how your specific asset is made, additionally provide screenshots or even share your file if it can help.
